# Use two derivative rules and iterate several times to get the simplest expression of higher derivative

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, special-functions, recursion

I have 2 rules of recursive relation of the derivative, I want to use it  several times get the higher derivative on `[\Theta]` of `P[\[Theta],n,m]` **only expressed by `P[\[Theta], n, m]` and `P[\[Theta], n-1, m]`**. (Yes, `P` is Associated Legendre polynomials here)

This is my rule (Sorry, I don't know how to wrap this long line of code):

```
rule1 = D[P[\[Theta], n, m], {\[Theta], i}] :> D[D[P[\[Theta], n, m], {\[Theta], i - 1}], {\[Theta], 1}];(*i>=2*)
rule2 = D[P[\[Theta], n, m], {\[Theta], 1}] :> 1/Sin[\[Theta]] (n Cos[\[Theta]]*P[\[Theta], n, m] - (n + m) P[\[Theta], n - 1, m]);
rule = {rule1, rule2};
```

Then I use this first code and it return the needed result.

```
D[P[\[Theta], n, m], {\[Theta], 1}] //. rule
```

However, the higher derivative on `[\Theta]` canot work. How to the let it works?

```
D[P[\[Theta], n, m], {\[Theta], 2}] //. rule (* return with calcuation *)
```

We can **make rule 1 execute first, consider rule 2 during the compute, and repeat the process** to get what I want. But how to implement it in code?

Another try (Try these two rules in each calculation step) :

```
r1 = D[P[\[Theta], n_, m], {\[Theta], 1}] :> (1/Sin[\[Theta]] (n Cos[\[Theta]]*P[\[Theta], n, m] - (n + m) P[\[Theta], n - 1, m]));
r2 = D[P[\[Theta], n_, m], {\[Theta], i_}] :> (D[D[P[\[Theta], n, m], {\[Theta], i - 1}] /. r1, \[Theta] ] /. r1);(*i>=2*)
D[P[\[Theta], n, m], {\[Theta], 2}] /. r2 (* Out contains P[\[Theta], -2 + n, m], This is not what you want to see *)
D[P[\[Theta], n, m], {\[Theta], 3}] /. r2 (* Nothing changed *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that MMA simplifies the exprerssion `D[D[P[\[Theta], n, m], {\[Theta], i - 1}], {\[Theta], 1}]`at once to `D[P[\[Theta], n, m], {\[Theta], i}]`. And you are where you started. To prevent this, we may formulate it in a recursive way. E.g.:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
p[1] = 1/
   Sin[\[Theta]] (n Cos[\[Theta]]*
     P[\[Theta], n, m] - (n + m) P[\[Theta], n - 1, m])
p[i_] := D[p[i - 1], \[Theta]];
```

Now with this we get e.g.:

```
p[2]
```

[image]

Or

```
p[3]
```

[image]

**A new editon base on the previous method**

```
ClearAll[f];
f[1,n_,m_,\[Theta]_]:=1/Sin[\[Theta]] (n Cos[\[Theta]]*f[0,n,m,\ 
 [Theta]]-(n+m)f[0,n-1,m,\[Theta]]);(*Eq.(8) at 
 https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLegendrePolynomial.html*)
 f[j_,n_,m_,\[Theta]_]:=FullSimplify@((D[f[j-1,n,m,\[Theta]],\ 
 [Theta]])//.{
    (*(f^(0,0,0,1))[j-2,n,m,\[Theta]]:>f[j-1,n,m,\[Theta]],
    (f^(0,0,0,1))[j-2,-1+n,m,\[Theta]]:>f[j-1,-1+n,m,\[Theta]],*)
    (f^(0,0,0,1))[0,n,m,\[Theta]]:>f[1,n,m,\[Theta]],
    (f^(0,0,0,1))[0,-1+n,m,\[Theta]]:>f[1,-1+n,m,\[Theta]],
    f[0,-2+n,m,\[Theta]]:>((-1+2 n) Cos[\[Theta]] f[0,-1+n,m,\[Theta]]+ 
    (m-n)f[0,n,m,\[Theta]])/(-1+m+n)
    })/;j>=2;
```

Try

```
    Table[f[j, n, m, \[Theta]], {j, 0, 4}] // TableForm
```

The out put is:
[image]
The above code works, but how to simplify them (Are there redundant items in the replacement rule??)?

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Huber. I modeyied your  good answer to further simplify the results.